# `pgfplots`: `const plot mark mid` with `\ref`

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing

I want to use the `const plot mark mid` style offered by `pgfplots` together with a `\ref` to the plot.
However the reference shows a glitch that is not present in the usual legend.
The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[const plot mark mid] coordinates {
(0,0.1) (0.1,0.15) (0.2,0.5) (0.3,0.62)
(0.4,0.3) (0.5,0.2) (0.6,0.25) (0.7,0.1)
}; \addlegendentry{works} \label{plot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{plot} broken
\end{document}
```

The resulting image looks like this

[image]

I get the same problem for `jump mark mid` but the problem is absent in both `const plot mark left` and `const plot mark right` as well as the corresponding `jump` styles.
Am I right to assume that this is a bug? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug which can be reproduced by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[yshift=0.3em] {
    \draw[const plot mark mid]
        plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};
}
\end{document}
```

For this effect to occur the following preconditions are needed:

- The option `const plot mark mid` must be set for the `\draw` command.
- The coordinate list of the plot must have at least three coordinates.
- The option `yshift` with a value other than zero must be set for the `\tikz` macro.

---

Since this effect only occurs with `const plot mark mid`, you can override the legend image via the option `legend image code` and tell it to use some other style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[const plot mark mid, 
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw[mark repeat=2, mark phase=2, const plot]
            plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.3cm,0cm) (0.6cm,0cm)};
    }] coordinates {
(0,0.1) (0.1,0.15) (0.2,0.5) (0.3,0.62)
(0.4,0.3) (0.5,0.2) (0.6,0.25) (0.7,0.1)
}; \addlegendentry{works} \label{plot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{plot} no longer broken
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bug reported: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1219#issue-1450437667

Comment: A proper solution has been provided by muzimuzhi at GitHub. It seems that the bug will be solved in the next version of Ti*k*Z/PGF.